# converting month to string

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have month and the Revenue and Goal against them. However, the months are in String format as "1","2", "3" etc. I want them as Jan, Feb, Mar etc. also the month should be sorted. I have written some basic code. However, it gives an error saying: **Invalid field monthString for SObject User_Stats__c**

Controller:

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesReps(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Sales_rep=[Select Id, Month__c, Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null ORDER BY Month__c];
    Sales_Rep.sort();
    return Sales_Rep;
}

public class SalesReps implements Comparable

{
public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
    return month-((SalesReps)o).month;
}
public Integer month { get; set; }
public String monthString { get; set; }    
public SalesReps(String mon, Double Reve, Double Gol)
{
    month = integer.valueof(mon);
    monthString = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(System.Date.newInstance(2000, month, 1), System.Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).formatGMT('MMM');                
}
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:pageblock >
   <apex:dataTable value="{!SalesReps}" var="rep" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F5FFFA">
        <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rep.monthString}">
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Oct Rental Revenue" value="{!rep.Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c}">
        </apex:column>            
        <apex:column headerValue="Oct Rental Goals" value="{!rep.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}">
        </apex:column>             
        <apex:column headerValue="Goal Revision">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rep.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:column>            
    </apex:dataTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, in the VF page you were trying to access properties of the inner (wrapper) class SalesRep, but the object source for the dataTable was of **List < User_Stats__c >** type.

Try to alter your controller to resemble something like this:

```
public List<SalesRep> getSalesReps(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    List<User_Stats__c> userStats =[SELECT Id, Month__c, Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c 
                                FROM User_Stats__c 
                                WHERE Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null 
                                ORDER BY Month__c];

    // Populate list of SalesRep (return type)
    List<SalesRep> salesReps = new List<SalesRep>();
    for(User_Stats__c us : userStats) {
        salesReps.add(new SalesRep(us.Month__c, us.Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, us.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c));
    }
    return salesReps;
}

public class SalesRep implements Comparable {
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        return month-((SalesRep)o).month;
    }
    public Integer month { get; set; }
    public String monthString { get; set; }    
    public SalesRep(String mon, Double Reve, Double Gol)
    {
        month = integer.valueof(mon);
        monthString = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(System.Date.newInstance(2000, month, 1), System.Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).formatGMT('MMM');                
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need further clarification.

---

**Edit #1** - to meet requirements specified in the comment:

> I already tried this solution. The problem with this is that the value
>   in input field are being used to update the User_Stats table. Hence I
>   was not able to use the wrapper class. Following is the code for
>   updating: public List Sales_Rep { get; set; } public
>   UserStatsController() { Sales_Rep = getSalesReps(); } public
>   PageReference save() { update Sales_Rep; return null; }

If you would like to edit properties of the underlying User_Stat__c object, you can still do that even if you use the wrapper class, since you can access the User_Stats__c objects by reference if you pass them to the wrapper class constructor. If you look at the altered constructor of the inner class, you will notice that it now accepts objects of type User_Stats__c as argument, and keeps a reference to that object. That way, you can access/edit properties of User_Stat__c in your VF page through a **UserStat** field of the inner class. Your page controller would now have to look like this:

```
public List<User_Stats__c> User_Stats { get; set; }
public List<SalesRep> Sales_Reps { get; set; } 

public UserStatsController() {
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    User_Stats =[SELECT Id, Month__c, Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c 
                    FROM User_Stats__c 
                    WHERE Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null 
                    ORDER BY Month__c];

    // Populate list of SalesRep
    Sales_Reps = new List<SalesRep>();
    for(User_Stats__c us : User_Stats) {
        Sales_Reps.add(new SalesRep(us));
    }
}

public PageReference save() { 
    update User_Stats; 
    return null; 
}

public class SalesRep implements Comparable {

    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        return month-((SalesRep)o).month;
    }

    public User_Stats__c UserStat { get; set; }
    public Integer month { get; set; }
    public String monthString { get; set; }    

    public SalesRep(User_Stats__c usrStat)
    {
        this.UserStat = usrStat;
        this.month = usrStat.Month__c;
        this.monthString = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(System.Date.newInstance(2000, month, 1), System.Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).formatGMT('MMM');
    }
}
```

Of course, you would have to update your VF page also:

```
<apex:pageblock >
   <apex:dataTable value="{!Sales_Reps}" var="rep" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" align="center" bgcolor="#F5FFFA">
        <apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rep.monthString}">
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Oct Rental Revenue" value="{!rep.UserStat.Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c}">
        </apex:column>            
        <apex:column headerValue="Oct Rental Goals" value="{!rep.UserStat.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}">
        </apex:column>             
        <apex:column headerValue="Goal Revision">
            <apex:inputField value="{!rep.UserStat.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:column>            
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: I already tried this solution. The problem with this is that the value in input field are being used to update the User_Stats table. Hence I was not able to use the wrapper class. Following is the code for updating: `public List<User_Stats__c> Sales_Rep { get; set; }
    
    public UserStatsController() {
        Sales_Rep = getSalesReps();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update Sales_Rep;
        return null;
    }`

Comment: is there an option to use Case...When in Select statement in visualforce?

Comment: Robin, you can still use the wrapper class and update the underlying User_Stats__c objects... See "Edit #1" addendum to my initial answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dino_zg. I tried your code. The code is not giving any error, but there is no values populated. I am trying to identify the reason. If something comes to your attention that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you look to be missing the closing `}` on the following line

`<apex:column headerValue="Sales Rep" value="{!rep.monthString">`

Comment: Oh. I corrected this. Must have missed out. However the error is still there **Invalid field monthString for SObject User_Stats__c**

Comment: It looks like you will need to create a list of a wrapper class which holds the User_Stats__c object along with your MonthString variables, this way you could acces both the salesforce fields on the User_Stats__c object and the monthString

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesReps(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Sales_rep=[Select Id, Month__c, Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null ORDER BY Month__c];
    Sales_Rep.sort();
     return Sales_Rep;
}
```

In the above method you are returning list of User_Stats__c and thats causing issue.

The return has to be a wrapper object SalesReps .You will need to form a wrapper SalesReps from your sobject User_Stats__c and return SalesReps object

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohit. I already tried wrapper class. The problem with this is that the value in input field are being used to update the User_Stats table. Hence I was not able to use the wrapper class. Following is the code for updating: `public List<User_Stats__c> Sales_Rep { get; set; }
    
    public UserStatsController() {
        Sales_Rep = getSalesReps();
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update Sales_Rep;
        return null;
    }`

Comment: is there an option to use Case...When in Select statement in visualforce?

Comment: I also have one more query. It will be great if you can help me with that too!: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24579/how-to-set-custom-order-of-a-series